# What's the official workflow/lifecycle diagram for the command events triggering in symfony?

Tags: symfony, events, command-line, console, listener

## Question

Just the same way that there are nice "official" infographics for the "Http Kernel" events workflow/lifecycle of the in Symfony, is there any diagram for the console events?

### Context

For example: you can see a chart of when the http kernel events are triggered here:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html

where you can see there "painted" in blue-colored boxes events like

```
kernel.request
kernel.controller
kernel.exception
kernel.view
kernel.terminate
[among others]
```

and in the middle, in purple-colored boxes the executions that the kernel does.

### For the command

I guess that, according to this https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/events.html the workflow must be something like this:

```
                                                                                                                     ...
                                                                                                                      |
                                                                                                                      V
                                                                                                            +--------------------+
                                                                                                            | dispatch the       |
                                                                                                            | console.exception  |
                                                                                                            | console.error (3.3)|
                                                                                                            +--------------------+
                                                                                                                      |
                                                                                                                      |
                                                                                                                      V
 /------------------\      +--------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+      /------------------\
/ command line       \     | Call the           |     | dispatch the       |     | Call the           |     | dispatch the       |     / flush output       \
| invocation         |---->| Command::configure |---->| console.command    |---->| Command::execute   |---->| console.terminate  |---->| buffer and return  |
\ from the bash      /     | of all commands    |     |                    |     | on selectd command |     |                    |     \ to the bash        /
 \------------------/      +--------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+     +--------------------+      \------------------/
```

So the question is if there is any "official" graphic for this from the symfony guys.

Thnx.